# How to create a long nested list that is sortable?

Tags: arrays, math, numbers

Description:

I want to create a list, ideally unlimited, but I can live with at least 1,000 initial items or so, which has an unlimited number of lists that can be created in between each of the initial list items, and the same between each subsequently created item, ad infinitum.

Idea 1:

The list starts with 1 item, let's call it `x`.
Then, I can add 1 item either to the left or to the right of `x`, if to the left, it needs to be smaller, to the right it needs to be bigger.
One attempt is to use integers, so if `x` is `500`, we now have `[499, 500, 501]` and we keep going `[498, 499, 500, 501, 502]`.
Now, I need to add an item in between items, for example between `500` and `501`, so let's use decimals and add `500.5`, then an item between `500.5` and `501`, so that'll be `500.75`, and so on…

Problem:

This method will only run for 38 times, until we reach `500.999999999999` after which, any program I've run, either programming language (JavaScript) or Excel will stop adding decimal positions.

Furthermore, I should then be able to go between `500.5` and `500.75` and again create a list in between, which will stop at `500.749999999999` after 37 iterations, and so on.

Idea 2:

Use letters. The result can then be sorted alphabetically. Start with `L`, to the left we add `K`, to the right we add `M`: `[K, L, M]`.
Between `L` and `M` we could create `LM`, then between `LM` and `M` we can add `LMM` and so on.

Problem:

The limitation with this one, is that to the left we can only go to `A` and to the right we can only reach `Z`, much less than the desired 1,000 items.

Does anyone have any suggestion? Perhaps a combination of letters and numbers? (But how to sort that?) or perhaps some formula I don't know about? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of multiple solutions. Which will work best depends on your programming language.

First, you could continue with your idea of float numbers, but use an extended precision package or a language with extended precision float numbers. In Python you could use the standard `decimal` module. Before you start, you can set the precision of your numbers high enough to cover the possible number of added numbers. For 1000 additions, using 302 decimal places would suffice. Some languages or packages have unlimited precision, where you do not need to set the precision in advance.

Second, you could use rational numbers. Python has the `fractions` module, and since Python's integers are arbitrary precision, so are the fractions.

Third, you could implement your own kind of fractions by using 2-tuples of positive integers. The tuple `(a, b)` 'represents' the positive rational number `a/b`, but you implement these 'rationals' yourself. You start with `(1, 1)`. Then `(a, b)` is less than `(c, d)` if and only if `a*d < b*c`. You make a tuple `(a, b)` smaller with `(a, b+1)` and you make it larger with `(a+1, b)`. You get a tuple between `(a, b)` and `(c, d)` with `(a+c, b+d)`. This works best if the integers are arbitrary precision.

Fourth, you could use 2-tuples with the first element an integer and the second a string. A tuple before `(0, 'A')` is `(-1, 'A')`, and a tuple after `(0, 'Z')` is `(0, 'ZA')`, or you could use `(1, 'Z')`. A tuple between `(0, 'A')` and `(0, 'B')` is `(0, 'AB')`, as you already know.

Fifth, you could simulate a Binary Search Tree (BST). Since you want a list rather than an actual BST, you simulate one by making each item in your list represent a node in a BST, where `'L'` represents a Left-son and `'R'` represents a Right-son. You start the list with the single item `''`, the empty string, which represents the root of the BST. To get an item to the left of the left-most item, concatenate `'L'` to the end of the string to get the desired item. To get an item to the right of the right-most item, concatenate `'R'` to the end of the string. To get an item between two adjacent items, we realize that one must be an initial part of the other. If the left item is longer than the right, concatenate a `'R'` to the left item. If the left item is shorter than the right, concatenate a `'L'` to the right item. Note that this method is isomorphic to using fractions starting at `1`, and adding an `'L'` is isomorphic to subtracting a power of `1/2` and adding an `'R` is isomorphic to adding a power of `1/2`. But the strings avoid the finite-precision problem.

I can think of other possibilities as well. If I were to implement your idea, I would go with the `fractions` in Python, since they are well-integrated into the language. Then ordering, printing, and so on are already handled in the language.

Comment: Thanks @Rory, if I store fractions, whether that looks like `a/b` or `(a, b)`, how do I then sort them ascending?

Comment: @trs: If you use Python, the fractions from the `fractions` module are treated as regular numbers. To sort the list, just use the `sort` method or `sorted` function--no special handling is needed. Printing a fraction or doing a `str` on it results in something like `a/b`. Doing a `repr` on it results in something like `Fraction(a, b)`. If you are not using Python, state which programming language and environment you are using and I may be able to give more specific recommendations. Also ask if you are using Python but do not understand the `fractions` module.